# Charaterization of waveguide to coaxial adapter

Tags: adapter, resonance, system, calibration, matrix

I'm trying a method to characterize a high frequency waveguide to coaxial adapter( 2-port network).

For this, I use 3 adapters A1, A2, A3. After a TRM calibration, I measure A1 connected with A2 with a VNA (cascade), then I get the S2P file. I repeat the manipulation with the another combinations (A1 with A3, A2 with A3).

I get 3 T-parameters matrix equations:

- [A1]×[A2]=[M1],
- [A1]×[A3]=[M2] and
- [A2]×[A3]=[M3],

where [Mi] are the T-parameters getting by the conversion of the S2P  files.

I deduce from those equations this equality:

[A2]^2=[M3]x[M2]^-1x[M1].

When I resolve this, I obtain the S-parameters of the adapter A2 by re-converting the coefficients. The problem is that  some resonance pic appears for both return losses and insertion losses at  given frequency and I don't know from where it comes. May someone could help me please?

Comment: I get \$A_2^2 = \dfrac{M_1\cdot M_3}{M_2}\$ but, maybe I'm not mathematically manipulating these as you want? BTW, to use mathjax, I did this: `\$A_2^2 = \dfrac{M_1\cdot M_3}{M_2}\$`

Comment: At what relative frequencies ? Can they be related to "dimensions" of adapters ? Or be related to how "assembling" adapters" ? Are you using a joint ? Are they matching impedances ?

Comment: For determining properties of one "component", I used the three possible "loads" that are "easy" to found. One is "short-circuit", other is "open end", third is "matching impedance". But it was in the past ... a long time ago ...

Comment: What is a VNA ?

Comment: Is VNA a Voltage Network Analyser ? Or reflectometer ?

Comment: @Andy Aka you're right I forgot to swap matrices

Comment: TRM= Thru Reflect Match

Comment: I think that the pic I see on the plot comes from the trace of the square matrix which is superior at that point than other traces

Comment: Shall I leave that as a formal answer @DODO

Comment: No. I m asking why the traces are so high at some frequencies.